# I want to update values in column, based on condition that need to compare data from another table

Tags: sql, oracle, calculated-columns

I need help on one case in SQL, so I have to fill one column DIFFERENCE with 'Above' or 'Below' in table CLIENTS, if the date in other column in table - DOCUMENT is above or below 4 months from now. I tried with this

```
UPDATE CLIENTS
SET DIFFERENCE = CASE WHEN MONTHS_BETWEEN(TO_DATE((SELECT DATA FROM DOCUMENT, CLIENTS WHERE DOCUMENT.ID_CLIENT=CLIENTS.ID_CLIENT ),'DD.MM.YYYY'),TO_DATE(SYSDATE,'DD.MM.YYYY')) < 4 THEN 'Below' ELSE 'Above' END
```

but it returns lot of values, so I tried to JOIN the tables and

```
UPDATE CLIENTS
SET DIFFERENCE = CASE WHEN MONTHS_BETWEEN(TO_DATE(DATA,'DD.MM.YYYY'),TO_DATE(SYSDATE,'DD.MM.YYYY')) < 4 THEN 'Below' ELSE 'Above' END
FROM CLIENTS  JOIN DOCUMENT
ON DOCUMENT.ID_CLIENT=CLIENTS.ID_CLIENT
```

but this time says Not properly ended.
I'm working with Oracle db.
Please if you see the answer, write me!

Thank you in advance!

```
 SELECT  CLIENTS.ID_CLIENT,MIN(DOCUMENT.DATA) AS "DATA"
    FROM DOCUMENT,CLIENTS
WHERE CLIENTS.ID_CLIENT=DOCUMENT.ID_CLIENT
GROUP BY CLIENTS.ID_CLIENT
```

and some of the results:

ID_CLIENT   DATA
54  01/23/2014
57  01/23/2014
78  01/23/2014
87  01/24/2014
91  01/24/2014

---

I found the solution,

```
UPDATE CLIENTS
SET DIFFERENCE = CASE WHEN MONTHS_BETWEEN(TO_DATE((SELECT MIN(DATA) FROM DOCUMENT, CLIENTS WHERE DOCUMENT.ID_CLIENT=CLIENTS.ID_CLIENT),'MM.DD.YYYY'),TO_DATE(SYSDATE,'MM.DD.YYYY')) < 4 THEN 'Below' ELSE 'Above' END
```

The mistake was 'MM.DD.YYYY' ... first I used 'DD.MM.YYYY' - very stupid mistake!

Thanks for all the answers!   ekad  YOU really helped me!!!

Comment: If there are both documents more and less than 4 months for the same client, what should `difference` be set to?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: Joachim Isaksson  you're right, I have to find solution for all of the documents of one client, and if there are documents where the months between the DATA are more than 4 months from now to say in column DIFFERENCE - ABOVE else BELOW

Comment: I assume `DOCUMENT.DATA` is a varchar, not date. Please try my updated answer below.

Comment: That was the problem! Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of joining the tables, you need to check whether there's any related documents with `DATA` more than 4 months from now using `EXISTS`. It also seems that `DOCUMENT.DATA` is a varchar and the value is set using mm/dd/yyyy format, so you need to change the second parameter of `TO_DATE` function to `MM/DD/YYYY`

```
UPDATE CLIENTS
SET DIFFERENCE = CASE WHEN EXISTS
                 (SELECT 1 FROM DOCUMENT
                  WHERE ID_CLIENT = CLIENTS.ID_CLIENT
                  AND MONTHS_BETWEEN(TO_DATE(DATA,'MM/DD/YYYY'),SYSDATE) > 4) 
                 THEN 'Above' 
                 ELSE 'Below' END
```

Comment: I tryed but it says:ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

Comment: Now it says: ORA-01779: cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table   Maybe this is because I have more than one document for each client, and sometimes it's above 4 months and sometimes below... and I have to use another solution?

Comment: Yes I think you're right. What's the criteria of setting `DIFFERENCE` to `'Below'` if there's more than one document for each client? Does all of them need to be less than 4 months than now?

Comment: Yes, to be "Below" all of them must be less than 4 months and if there is any document greater than 4 months must set "Above"

Comment: Yes, to be "Below" all of them must be less than 4 months and if there is any document greater than 4 months must set "Above"     I tried `SELECT  CLIENTS.ID_CLIENT,MIN(DOCUMENT.DATA) AS "DATA"
    FROM DOCUMENT,CLIENTS
WHERE CLIENTS.ID_CLIENT=DOCUMENT.ID_CLIENT
GROUP BY CLIENTS.ID_CLIENT`  and now I have the MIN data of document...and if this data is greater than 4 months...I have to use this info for the case logic

Comment: NOW   ORA-01843: not a valid month .     I think this is because there are many dates for one client, not only one.

Comment: What's the data type of `DATA` column? Can you edit your question and add some sample data?